# MySQL query predominant non-numeric value

Tags: mysql, text, max, average

I'm looking for a function to return the most predominant non numeric value from a table.

My database table records readings from a weatherstation. Many of these are numeric, but wind direction is recorded as one of 16 text values - N,NNE,NE,ENE,E... etc in a varchar field. Records are added every 15 minutes so 95 rows represent a day's weather.

I'm trying to compute the predominant wind direction for the day. Manually you would add together the number of Ns, NNEs, NEs etc and see which there are most of.

Has MySQL got a neat way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You could define the wind directions as an enum -- so in the backend you are having integer again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question without seeing your schema, but this should help you.

Assuming the wind directions are stored in the same column as the numeric values you want to ignore, you can use [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html) to ignore the numeric values, like this:

```
select generic_string, count(*)
from your_table
where day = '2014-01-01'
and generic_string not regexp '^[0-9]*$'
group by generic_string
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

If wind direction is the only thing stored in the column then it's a little simpler:

```
select wind_direction, count(*)
from your_table
where day = '2014-01-01'
group by wind_direction
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

You can do this for multiple days using sub-queries. For example (assuming you don't have any data in the future) this query will give you the most common wind direction for each day in the current month:

```
select this_month.day,
(
  select winddir 
  from weatherdatanum 
  where thedate >= this_month.day
  and thedate < this_month.day + interval 1 day
  group by winddir
  order by count(*) desc
  limit 1
) as daily_leader
from
(
  select distinct date(thedate) as day
  from weatherdatanum
  where thedate >= concat(left(current_date(),7),'-01') - interval 1 month
) this_month
```

Comment: Brilliant! The second option is fine as wind_dir has it's own column. Could you help me extend this just a little. I'd like to return the daily values for a whole month. Here is your code plus my modifications which doesn't quite work:

select thedate, winddir, count(*)
from  weatherdatanum
where month(thedate)=#dateformat(now(),"mm")#
group by winddir,year(thedate),month(thedate), day(thedate)
order by count(*) desc
limit 1

Comment: What is the data type of the `thedate` column?

Comment: It's datetime and the site is coded using Coldfusion if the #dateformat(now(),"mm")# looks unfamiliar. Thanks

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include an example that calculates the daily leaders for all days in the current month.

Comment: That's perfect - thanks so much for your prompt and expert help. You can see the result of your input here: http://weather.lewannick.info/archive.cfm
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should return you a list of wind directions along with counts sorted by most occurrences:

```
SELECT wind_dir, COUNT(wind_dir) AS count FROM `mytable` GROUP BY wind_dir ORDER DESC
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your time! Best wishes.